Sed regex find a string in yaml and comment line, preserving indentation
Let's say I have the below yaml:
parent:
  A:
    name: foo
    value: x.y.z # check=something
    # value: "yay" # check=nothing

  B:
    name: bar
    value: p.q.r # check=something
    # value: "yay" # check=nothing

Note the "#" to the A.value and B.value lines which have the "check=nothing" string, is within the formatted indentation and NOT at the beginning of the line in the file.
Case 1: In certain situations, I want to uncomment all the lines that have "check=nothing" string in the line, but also preserve the indentation. So the output should be like below:
parent:
  A:
   ...
   value: "yay" # check=nothing

  B:
   ...
   value: "yay" # check=nothing

I have tried the below regex, this removes the comment but doesn't preserve the indentation:
'/check=something/s/^[ \t]*# //g'

Case 2: In certain situations, I want to comment the lines that have "check=something" string in it like the below output:
parent:
  A:
    name: foo
    # value: x.y.z # check=something
    ...
  
  B:
    name: bar
    # value: p.q.r # check=something
    ...

And I have tried the below regex, it comments, but it doesn't preserve the indentation:
'/type=dotdev/ s/^[ \t]*#*/# /g'

So in effect, only one of the value:* lines within this yaml will be applicable based on some other logic, but I have to use the check=* to do the relevant sed regex.
I have tried the below regexes as well. This works but the placement of the "#" or the expectation of the "#" is at the beginning of the line (instead of an indented "#") and that ends up looking ugly.
'/check=something/ s/^#*/#/g' --> For commenting. This adds '#' to the beginning of the line

'/check=nothing/^#//g' --> For uncommenting, but expects the "#" to be at the beginning of the line.

What am I missing in my sed regex so that I can preserve the indentation?

Case 1: search (^\s*)#\s(.*)$, replace $1$2, see: https://regex101.com/r/9rvZlr/1  (oops, it's just replacing the commented lines by an uncommented line.... )

So, it can be:  search: (^\s*)#\s(?=.*# check=nothing)(.*)$, replace $1$2,  see: https://regex101.com/r/yfKOET/1

Case2 is a small variation on case1: search: (^\s*)(?=.*# check=something)(.*)$, replace $1# $2, see: https://regex101.com/r/v5SAp8/1

@Luuk Pardon me for this question. I am trying the below from within a shell script:
sed -i 's/(^\s*)#\s(?=.check=nothing)(.)$/$1$2/g' "./test.yaml".   But this does not do anything. It leaves the test.yaml file as is. But regex101 actually shows the  matches and the substitution happen. What am I doing wrong here?

@shelter that would cause a false match if the # appeared after check-nothing or before it in some other context than a leading comment start, etc.

@Luuk only GNU sed would take \s as meaning "a space character" and no sed would recognize (?=... as that's PCRE syntax, not BRE as sed understands by default, nor ERE as GNU and BSD seds understand when using the -E flag. Running it in regex101 is not a good way to try to verify a regexp for a command-line tool

In case 2, should a line like # value: p.q.r # check=something end up as # # value: p.q.r # check=something or remain # value: p.q.r # check=something?

Using any sed:
$ sed 's/^\([ \t]*\)#[ \t]*\(.*check=nothing\)/\1\2/' file
parent:
  A:
    name: foo
    value: x.y.z # check=something
    value: "yay" # check=nothing

  B:
    name: bar
    value: p.q.r # check=something
    value: "yay" # check=nothing

and 1 possible interpretation of your case 2 requirements (don't comment a line that's already commented) would be:
$ sed 's/^\([ \t]*\)\([^#].*check=something\)/\1# \2/' file
parent:
  A:
    name: foo
    # value: x.y.z # check=something
    # value: "yay" # check=nothing

  B:
    name: bar
    # value: p.q.r # check=something
    # value: "yay" # check=nothing

The second one assumes there will always be some non-space, non-# character before check=something.

note that this will change lines like # value: "check=nothing" # check=something but that may not be an issue

@jhnc right, I'm just showing how to do what the OP said they wanted to do but there are various potentially problematic scenarios not covered by the OPs sample input, output including the one you mentioned and # value: "yay" paycheck=nothingness, etc.

Thank you. This works for what I wanted.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
First case:
sed -E '/check=nothing/s/^(\s*)#\s*/\1/' file

Second case:
sed -E '/check=something/s/^(\s*)(#\s*)*/\1# /' file

N.B. The first grouping preserves the indentation. Also in the second case, if the line is already commented the line is not doubly commented.

It is not working with sed, because that does not support lookahead (the (?=...) part) in a regular expression.
An option might be to use gawk, which also can do inplace updates
gawk -i inplace '{ if($0 ~ /# check=nothing/){ sub(/# /,""); print $0 } else { print $0 }}' test.yaml

Short explanation:
In (g)awk $0 represents a line that is being read from the input file. gawk processes all input lines.
When the line matches the regular expression /# check=nothing/ is will replace #  (see: sub)
